# interpolation issue between 2 matrixes

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two matrixes: (time,observation) and (time,model).

What I need to do is match the model data time resolution to the observation data (they're on different timescales).

Until now, I have been able to do so using simple interpolation.

However, using my latest model some of the time data overlaps (I get an error in matlab that reads: "x values should be distinct").

Any ideas as how to most elegantly fix this problem?

Comment: can you post a small example of data and the code you have used so far?

Comment: Average your data at points with equal time (using for example `accumarray`) and then interpolate

Answer (score 0):

If in your model, time points really have duplicates, then I would hope that the corresponding model predictions are identical.

In that way, a model prediction is different from an observation: a second measurement at the same time point helps constrain your model, but evaluating a model twice at the same time point is of no use.

To discard duplicate model predictions, you could use `unique`. If your model predictions are stored in a matrix `M` with two columns, one for the time stamp and one for the prediction, you could eliminate duplicate predictions with `M = unique(M, 'rows');`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is your problem:

```
X1 = [1 2 3]
Y1 = [10 20 30]
X2 = [0.9 2 2.1]
Y2 = [21 21 21]
```

And that you want to use the values from both vectors for interpolation.

Here is what you can do:

First create a list of unique x values, then find the corresponding y values. For example the mean. After this you can continue with your process as before.